# Using Jquery to pop in a div from the side.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jquery and have a simple question.  I have tried every which way to move the div from popping in from the top to popping in from the right. I have tried manipulating the js to move the div to the right, manipulating the css so that the div appears in a different place, but I can never get past only being able to move the div horizontally. Please enlighten me on how I can do this. :)

```
(function($){

/* Converting an element into a bounce box: */
$.fn.bounceBox = function(){

    /*
        Applying some CSS rules that center the
        element in the middle of the page and
        move it above the view area of the browser.
    */

    this.css({
        top     : -this.outerHeight(),
        marginLeft  : -this.outerWidth()/2,
        position    : 'fixed',
        left        : '50%'
    });

    return this;
}

/* The boxShow method */
$.fn.bounceBoxShow = function(){

    /* Starting a downward animation */

    this.stop().animate({top:0});
    this.data('bounceShown',true);
    return this;
}

/* The boxHide method */
$.fn.bounceBoxHide = function(){

    /* Starting an upward animation */

    this.stop().animate({top:-this.outerHeight()});
    this.data('bounceShown',false);
    return this;
}

/* And the boxToggle method */
$.fn.bounceBoxToggle = function(){

    /* 
        Show or hide the bounceBox depending
        on the 'bounceShown' data variable
    */

    if(this.data('bounceShown'))
        this.bounceBoxHide();
    else
        this.bounceBoxShow();

    return this;
}

})(jQuery);
$(document).ready(function(){

/* Converting the #box div into a bounceBox: */
$('#box').bounceBox();
$('#box').css('left');
/* Listening for the click event and toggling the box: */
$('a.button').click(function(e){
    $('#box').bounceBoxToggle();
    e.preventDefault();
});

/* When the box is clicked, hide it: */
$('#box').click(function(){
    $('#box').bounceBoxHide();
});
});
```

Here is the JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/pzVxd/

Thank you for your help!

(disclosure: I got this code from a tutorialzine article.)

Comment: You mean, you have this, and you want others to make it do that ?

Comment: @MilchePatern I understand that it seems that I am asking for someone to just do it for me, but I tried every which way with limited knowledge to make it happen to no avail. Thanks for at least looking.

Comment: @MilchePatern Thanks for your input, regardless of your tone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I quickly modified your code to make it pop from the right. Is it just that what you want?

**First, I modified $this.css as follows:**

```
this.css({
    right           : -this.outerWidth(),
    marginTop   : -this.outerHeight()/2,
    position    : 'fixed',
    bottom      : '50%'
});
```

**Then I modified the *boxShow* and *boxHide* functions as follows:**

```
$.fn.bounceBoxShow = function(){

/* Starting a downward animation */

    this.stop().animate({right:0});
    this.data('bounceShown',true);
    return this;
}

/* The boxHide method */
$.fn.bounceBoxHide = function(){

    /* Starting an upward animation */

    this.stop().animate({right:-this.outerWidth()});
    this.data('bounceShown',false);
    return this;
}
```

Let me know if this works for you as you intend it to.